# Transform Multiple rows of JSON format to SQL table

Tags: sql, json, azure-blob-storage

I have JSON file in Blob Storage that looks like this:

```
{
  "Id": "****************************",
  "Status": "OK",
  "ProviderName": "Xero API Previewer",
  "DateTimeUTC": "\/Date(1576561543598)\/",
  "Invoices": [
    {
      "Type": "ACCPAY",
      "InvoiceID": "*****************************",
      "InvoiceNumber": "457489",
      "Reference": "",
      "Payments": [],
      "CreditNotes": [],
      "Prepayments": [],
      "Overpayments": [],
      "AmountDue": 0.00,
      "AmountPaid": 0.00,
      "AmountCredited": 0.00,
      "CurrencyRate": 1.000000,
      "IsDiscounted": false,
      "HasAttachments": false,
      "HasErrors": false,
      "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "************************************",
        "Name": "********************",
        "Addresses": [],
        "Phones": [],
        "ContactGroups": [],
        "ContactPersons": [],
        "HasValidationErrors": false
      },
      "DateString": "2102-11-26T00:00:00",
      "Date": "\/Date(4193942400000+0000)\/",
      "DueDateString": "2012-11-28T00:00:00",
      "DueDate": "\/Date(1354060800000+0000)\/",
      "Status": "VOIDED",
      "LineAmountTypes": "Inclusive",
      "LineItems": [
        {
          "Description": "Parking ",
          "UnitAmount": 465.01,
          "TaxType": "INPUT2",
          "TaxAmount": 60.65,
          "LineAmount": 465.01,
          "AccountCode": "274",
          "Tracking": [
            {
              "Name": "Region",
              "Option": "New Zealand",
              "TrackingCategoryID": "****************************************",
              "Options": []
            },
            {
              "Name": "Owner",
              "Option": "Head Office",
              "TrackingCategoryID": "***************************************",
              "Options": []
            }
          ],
          "Quantity": 1.0000,
          "LineItemID": "**************************************"
        }
      ],
      "SubTotal": 404.36,
      "TotalTax": 60.65,
      "Total": 465.01,
      "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1355876228590+0000)\/",
      "CurrencyCode": "NZD"
    },
    {
      "Type": "ACCPAY",
      "InvoiceID": "**************************************",
      "InvoiceNumber": "176295-01",
      "Reference": "",
      "Payments": [
        {
          "PaymentID": "********************************************",
          "Date": "\/Date(1576454400000+0000)\/",
          "Amount": 137.43,
          "Reference": "",
          "CurrencyRate": 1.000000,
          "HasAccount": false,
          "HasValidationErrors": false
        }
      ],
      "CreditNotes": [],
      "Prepayments": [],
      "Overpayments": [],
      "AmountDue": 0.00,
      "AmountPaid": 137.43,
      "AmountCredited": 0.00,
      "CurrencyRate": 1.000000,
      "IsDiscounted": false,
      "HasAttachments": true,
      "HasErrors": false,
      "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "************************************",
        "Name": "InkWorks",
        "Addresses": [],
        "Phones": [],
        "ContactGroups": [],
        "ContactPersons": [],
        "HasValidationErrors": false
      },
      "DateString": "2019-12-17T00:00:00",
      "Date": "\/Date(1576540800000+0000)\/",
      "DueDateString": "2020-01-20T00:00:00",
      "DueDate": "\/Date(1579478400000+0000)\/",
      "Status": "PAID",
      "LineAmountTypes": "Inclusive",
      "LineItems": [
        {
          "Description": "general stationery",
          "UnitAmount": 137.43,
          "TaxType": "INPUT2",
          "TaxAmount": 17.93,
          "LineAmount": 137.43,
          "AccountCode": "273",
          "Tracking": [
            {
              "Name": "Owner",
              "Option": "Head Office",
              "TrackingCategoryID": "******************************",
              "Options": []
            }
          ],
          "Quantity": 1.0000,
          "LineItemID": "****************************************"
        }
      ],
      "SubTotal": 119.50,
      "TotalTax": 17.93,
      "Total": 137.43,
      "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1576524509820+0000)\/",
      "CurrencyCode": "NZD",
      "FullyPaidOnDate": "\/Date(1576454400000+0000)\/"
    },
```

I want to store LineItems into a Table with columns as follows:
InvoiceID    LineItemID     Description     LineAmount      AccountCode     Date

There can be multiple LineItems in a single invoice.

I managed to get the top level only with the following code.

```
   WITH cte AS (
   SELECT CAST (BulkColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS jsonData
   FROM 
   OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'temp/XeroJson.json',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'test'
 --  FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'test'
   , SINGLE_CLOB
   ) AS blob
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM cte
   CROSS APPLY
   OPENJSON(cte.jsonData) j
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my test .json file, I placed it in my storage account :
[image]

```
{
    "Id": "****************************",
    "Status": "OK",
    "ProviderName": "Xero API Previewer",
    "DateTimeUTC": "\/Date(1576561543598)\/",
    "Invoices":
    [
    {
            "Type": "ACCPAY",
            "InvoiceID": "123456",
            "InvoiceNumber": "457489",
            "Reference": "",
            "Payments": [],
            "CreditNotes": [],
            "Prepayments": [],
            "Overpayments": [],
            "AmountDue": 0.00,
            "AmountPaid": 0.00,
            "AmountCredited": 0.00,
            "CurrencyRate": 1.000000,
            "IsDiscounted": false,
            "HasAttachments": false,
            "HasErrors": false,
            "Contact": {
                "ContactID": "************************************",
                "Name": "********************",
                "Addresses": [],
                "Phones": [],
                "ContactGroups": [],
                "ContactPersons": [],
                "HasValidationErrors": false
            },
            "DateString": "2102-11-26T00:00:00",
            "Date": "\/Date(4193942400000+0000)\/",
            "DueDateString": "2012-11-28T00:00:00",
            "DueDate": "\/Date(1354060800000+0000)\/",
            "Status": "VOIDED",
            "LineAmountTypes": "Inclusive",
            "LineItems": [{
                    "Description": "Parking ",
                    "UnitAmount": 465.01,
                    "TaxType": "INPUT2",
                    "TaxAmount": 60.65,
                    "LineAmount": 465.01,
                    "AccountCode": "274",
                    "Tracking": [{
                            "Name": "Region",
                            "Option": "New Zealand",
                            "TrackingCategoryID": "****************************************",
                            "Options": []
                        }, {
                            "Name": "Owner",
                            "Option": "Head Office",
                            "TrackingCategoryID": "***************************************",
                            "Options": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "Quantity": 1.0000,
                    "LineItemID": "**************************************"
                },
                {
                    "Description": "Parking2 ",
                    "UnitAmount": 111.11,
                    "TaxType": "INPUT2",
                    "TaxAmount": 60.65,
                    "LineAmount": 465.01,
                    "AccountCode": "276",
                    "Tracking": [{
                            "Name": "Region",
                            "Option": "New Zealand",
                            "TrackingCategoryID": "****************************************",
                            "Options": []
                        }, {
                            "Name": "Owner",
                            "Option": "Head Office",
                            "TrackingCategoryID": "***************************************",
                            "Options": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "Quantity": 1.0000,
                    "LineItemID": "**************************************"
                }
            ],
            "SubTotal": 404.36,
            "TotalTax": 60.65,
            "Total": 465.01,
            "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1355876228590+0000)\/",
            "CurrencyCode": "NZD"
        }, 
        {
            "Type": "ACCPAY",
            "InvoiceID": "1234567",
            "InvoiceNumber": "176295-01",
            "Reference": "",
            "Payments": [{
                    "PaymentID": "********************************************",
                    "Date": "\/Date(1576454400000+0000)\/",
                    "Amount": 137.43,
                    "Reference": "",
                    "CurrencyRate": 1.000000,
                    "HasAccount": false,
                    "HasValidationErrors": false
                }
            ],
            "CreditNotes": [],
            "Prepayments": [],
            "Overpayments": [],
            "AmountDue": 0.00,
            "AmountPaid": 137.43,
            "AmountCredited": 0.00,
            "CurrencyRate": 1.000000,
            "IsDiscounted": false,
            "HasAttachments": true,
            "HasErrors": false,
            "Contact": {
                "ContactID": "************************************",
                "Name": "InkWorks",
                "Addresses": [],
                "Phones": [],
                "ContactGroups": [],
                "ContactPersons": [],
                "HasValidationErrors": false
            },
            "DateString": "2019-12-17T00:00:00",
            "Date": "\/Date(1576540800000+0000)\/",
            "DueDateString": "2020-01-20T00:00:00",
            "DueDate": "\/Date(1579478400000+0000)\/",
            "Status": "PAID",
            "LineAmountTypes": "Inclusive",
            "LineItems": [{
                    "Description": "general stationery",
                    "UnitAmount": 137.43,
                    "TaxType": "INPUT2",
                    "TaxAmount": 17.93,
                    "LineAmount": 137.43,
                    "AccountCode": "273",
                    "Tracking": [{
                            "Name": "Owner",
                            "Option": "Head Office",
                            "TrackingCategoryID": "******************************",
                            "Options": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "Quantity": 1.0000,
                    "LineItemID": "****************************************"
                }
            ],
            "SubTotal": 119.50,
            "TotalTax": 17.93,
            "Total": 137.43,
            "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1576524509820+0000)\/",
            "CurrencyCode": "NZD",
            "FullyPaidOnDate": "\/Date(1576454400000+0000)\/"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the first invoice has two lineItems for demo here.

This is my sql script to exract from the json from storage :

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AccessAzureInvoices
WITH
     IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'
--   REMOVE ? FROM THE BEGINNING OF THE SAS TOKEN
,    SECRET = '<YOUR STORAGE SAS TOKEN>'
;

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices
WITH
(    LOCATION   = 'https://<YOUR STORAGE NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER NAME WHERE YOUR JSON FILE IN>'
,    CREDENTIAL = AccessAzureInvoices
,    TYPE       = BLOB_STORAGE
)
;

DECLARE @jsonVariable NVARCHAR(MAX); 
 set @jsonVariable = (select * from  OPENROWSET(
   BULK '<YOUR JSON FILE NAME>.json',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   SINGLE_CLOB
   ) AS  blob)


select * from (
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonVariable,N'$.Invoices')  WITH (
    InvoiceID  VARCHAR(200) N'$.InvoiceID',
    Date VARCHAR(200) N'$.Date',
    LineItems NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.LineItems' as json
))as table1 

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(LineItems) with (
LineAmount VARCHAR(200) '$.LineAmount',
AccountCode VARCHAR(200)'$.AccountCode',
LineItemID VARCHAR(200) '$.LineItemID',
Description VARCHAR(200) '$.Description'
)
```

Result : 
[image]

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you very much. It is now working as I wanted.